Where are the bad and good lattice basis for LWE's ciphertext: (as+e+Δm, a)?
Letś talk about LWE with 2 dimensions. I've seen somewhere they talking about encrypting with the good basis (public key) and then only the bad basis can decrypt.
I assume that the bad basis is the secret key $s=(s_1,s_2)$ but if so, then which is the good basis?
Usually a public key in LWE is $p=(as+e, a)$ and an encryption using this public key is $up+e+Δm$ for some random u to add randomness to the freshly encrypted value, otherwise simply doing $p + m$ would work.
SO, geometrically, where is the public basis in this scheme? What about RLWE, can we visualize it or do we rely on a LWE reduction?

Could you please provide some references in your question? I have heard of "messy keys' from GVP08 paper https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/432.pdf. But, I'm not sure whether you are talking about these keys.
